# Swift back button not showing in UINav bar

Tags: swift

I have got this simple code in my Swift code

```
let PostPage = PostView()
navigationController?.pushViewController(PostPage, animated: true)

class PostView: UIViewController
```

And this code does what it's supposed to do,which is to show `PostView`,but when this view is shown i expect that UINavbar's title will be changed and the back button will be shown.But none of that happens

[image]
[image]

in AppDelegate

```
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabNavigator())
```

Comment: What does appear?

Comment: @NRitH PostView with UINavbar

Comment: What VC was shown before the push?

Comment: The VC in which i call `let PostPage = PostView()
navigationController?.pushViewController(PostPage, animated: true)`

Comment: can you share the code what you are doing before pushing the PostView controller. also the screen shot of before + after the push?

Comment: @saroshmirza i don't do anything related to these before pushing and i'll present teh before and after screenshots now

Comment: @saroshmirza i added it

Comment: @sakoaskoaso great. can you also show how it looks in the storyboard / xib file?

Comment: @saroshmirza i don't have a storyboard i only work programmatically

Comment: Can you post the code where you change your nav title and anything related?

Comment: are you sure there exists a navigation controller and your tab bar controller is in the hierarchy?

Comment: @antonio081014 i only change nav title once and it's not related to this

Comment: Well you can see nav controller in the photos and what do you mean hierarchy?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso can you please share the code where you are initializing your navigation controller and settings its root view controller?

Comment: @saroshmirza i added it to the question

Comment: can you please share what's in your app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: @saroshmirza that's a big code and it's unrelated to the question thus i posted it here: https://pastebin.com/6LFEXju5

Comment: @saroshmirza why did you leave?

Comment: @sakoaskoaso, haven't left just trying out what can possibly go wrong .

Comment: @sakoaskoaso, i tried something. Don't have the right reasoning for it, but it started showing me the back button.
Seems like the problem is here 

`UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white,NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue:UIFont(name: "Open Sans", size: 24)!]`

Can you try commenting it out in your app delegate and check if the back button appears?

Comment: @saroshmirza i commented it still not working though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151312/discussion-between-sarosh-mirza-and-sakoaskoaso).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are changing the rootViewController from NavigationController to a ViewController.

```
let homeTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController:HomePage())
self.viewControllers = [homeTab]
```

Thus the rootViewController is no longer a navigationController.